# GNU make - rule in makefile in $(MAKEFILES) is not read/acknowledged

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile, `ImpTarget.mk`, defined with following content, [taken from this example](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding-Makefiles):

```
%.h: %.dummy_force
    @echo header= $@ xyz

%.dummy_force: ;
```

I include this file in the [`MAKEFILES` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKEFILES-Variable.html#MAKEFILES-Variable)

This is my top-level makefile (modified with the MAKEFILES variable)

```
MAKEFILES = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\ImpTarget.mk"

all:
    $(MAKE) -C src -f makefile_gen all
    $(MAKE) -C src DEBUG=TRUE -f makefile_gen all
```

My goal is to turn all files - .h, .cpp, etc - in the prerequisites list into targets also i.e., executing `make --print-database` should yield a statement that every header file is also a target.

However, it's not working.

When I look at the database printed out, for each makefile I see that `MAKEFILES` is equal to `"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\ImpTarget.mk"` which is good because it means that it should be reading in `ImpTarget.mk`

> [3.4 The Variable MAKEFILES](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKEFILES-Variable.html#MAKEFILES-Variable)
>
> If the environment variable MAKEFILES is defined, make considers its
>   value as a list of names (separated by whitespace) of additional
>   makefiles to be read before the others.

But it is not turning each file into a target. I still get:

```
# Not a target:
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/qt5binaries/include/QtCore/qglobalstatic.h:
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Last modified 2016-05-12 10:10:13
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
```

In fact, the rule I defined is not even showing up in the `--print-data-base` part of the output.

I put the `xyz` as a marker so I could easily locate it in the listing of the rules that are executed but it doesn't appear in that list.

**Why not use `include`?**

Well first of all, what's the difference? Show me a link.

Secondly, yes that's the preferred method but some of my makefiles auto-generate a makefile, then inside that one generate another makefile and execute it.

So I don't have control over my build system enough to do that.

Comment: Lots of "updates" here. Could you make this into a single, cohesive, coherent question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit they're updates as I tried different things. Summarized the comments from other answers in one place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I realized my updates were not in scope of original question so I trimmed a lot and now it's back on topic :)

Comment: Cool. All that's left now is to move the solution into an answer. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's the answer that @user657267 gave me: "running `make MAKEGILES=foo.mk`"

Comment: I understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the **environment variable** `MAKEFILES` is defined

Meaning make will only consider `MAKEFILES` if it is defined externally to make, either in the shell environment itself or by running `make MAKEFILES=foo.mk`.

`MAKEFILES` vs `include` is explained in the next paragraph

> The main use of `MAKEFILES` is in communication between recursive invocations of make

Comment: If I can't use `include`, is my only option `MAKEFILES` (used as you described)? Can I somehow pass a rule in the invocation of `make`? Or is that what the purpose of `MAKEFILES` is?

Comment: But in that case why did not my sub makes correctly use MAKEFLAGS?

Comment: You can pass a rule with `--eval` I guess, but if you're using make recursively then `MAKEFILES` is exactly what you need. You'll need to declare it with `export MAKEFILES` if you want to pass it to sub makes.

Comment: I plan on also, eventually, doing parallel builds using `--jobs`. Manual says [The main use of MAKEFILES is in communication between recursive invocations of make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKEFILES-Variable) will modifying `MAKEFILES` mess with `--jobs` option?

Comment: @Adrian No, that would be `MAKEFLAGS`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the `MAKEFILE` variable into the environment. From [6.10 Variables from the Environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html)

> When `make` runs a recipe, variables defined in the makefile are placed into the environment of each shell. This allows you to pass values to sub-`make` invocations (see Recursive Use of make). By default, only variables that came from the environment or the command line are passed to recursive invocations. You can use the export directive to pass other variables. See [Communicating Variables to a Sub-make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#Variables_002fRecursion), for full details.

Since `MAKEFILES` wasn't found in the original environment, it isn't automatically passed into the environment. Use:

```
export MAKEFILES = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\ImpTarget.mk"
```

Comment: But then why was the variable makefiles correctly populated in all of the invocations of the sub makes?

Comment: I understand the `export` functionality but what I'm not clear on is: does the export apply to ***ALL*** sub-makes children, grandchildren, etc OR just to the immediate sub-makes? [The documentation is not clear to me](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html) `Variable values of the top-level make can be passed to the sub-make through the environment by explicit request.`

Comment: I think it should apply to all. When you put a variable in the environment, that environment is inherited by all descendants, unless one of the intermediate processes explicitly removes it. But `make` shouldn't do that.

Comment: So put that line `export MAKEFILES = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\ImpTarget.mk"` in top-level `make` and should work for everything? Got it. Will try.